# Ununtu 15.10 desktop on a HP Laptop Video Driver Issues Nvida

Tags: drivers, nvidia, icons

I have a HP G60-445DX laptop that I installed Ubuntu Desktop 15.10 on.  The install went great using a CD with a ISO image and installed it to run directly on the laptop.  I selected most of the default options except for 2 which were I allowed for updates and I also selected to download additional drivers for ie music and other type stuff.  Once the install completed it asked me to remove disk and reboot the machine.  Did this once it came up and i logged in with my creds all I had was a mouse pointer and the default ubuntu screen with no icons.  So I said awe must not be able to run 15.10.  So I downloaded a 14.04.3 and installed it the same way I did 15.10 and when prompted to remove 15.10 and run a fresh install overwriting the entire drive and installing 14.04.02 i did.  Well guess what no icons there either.  So now I have gone back to 15.10 still no icons.  The video card i am using is NVIDA GeForce 8200M G  am i missing something.

Comment: Correction I installed 14.04.3 not 02 as stated in the first comment.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.  Yea I figured it out on my own big pat on my back as a new user.  Here is what I did.

ctrl alt f1 (to get to CLI)

sudo apt-get install NVidia-current

sudo reboot

and then it worked.

Thanks